# texdoc gives different results

Tags: texdoc, texlive-2019

My setup: TeXLive 2019 on a Mac

I try to get the documentation for the package `paralist`. So I issue the command

```
 $ texdoc paralist
```

on the command line. The first PDF that opens is “The parskip package”. Now I run the command again and the documentation for “ltxtable: longtable meets tabularx” opens.

Question: how to use texdoc to get the correct result?

Comment: I get paralist.pdf. What do you get with `texdoc -l paralist`? And do you actually have the package and the docu?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually I did not have the package installed... shame on me. But for UX, I'd expect a "can't find that documentation" instead of "can't find the documentation, I give you $random documentation instead".

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure the package you are looking for is installed on your computer. Texdoc cannot find documents of packages that are not installed.

In case Texdoc cannot find any documentation for the input keyword, just like in your case, Texdoc (v3.0 or later) will automatically perform the fuzzy search. You can check whether or not the fuzzy search was performed and the result of it by using the `-v` option, e.g.,

```
$ texdoc -v texdox
texdoc info: Fuzzy search result: texdoc
```

Moreover, if there are multiple package names which have the same similarity (i.e., the Levenshtein distance) to the input keyword, at this point, Texdoc randomly selects one of the candidates for the result. In your case, "parskip" and "carlisle" (note that ltxtable is part of the package "carlisle") have the same Levenshtein distance, which is 4, from the keyword "paralist", so the result got randomness.

If you don't want Texdoc to have any randomness for its result, you can turn off the fuzzy search feature by writing the following line in your configuration file (`texdoc.cnf`):

```
fuzzy_level = 0
```

Just for your information, you can check where you should put the configuration file by:

```
$ texdoc -f
```